# Functional equivalent of comparing two Lists

Tags: scala

Below code compares two Lists and if one element is contained in another List then the element is outputted :

```
  var containList = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String]()
                                                  //> containList  : scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer()
  val lines2 = List("2", "3", "4")                //> lines2  : List[String] = List(2, 3, 4)
  for (l <- lines2) {
    isStringInFile(l)
  }

  def isStringInFile(str: String) = {
    val lines = List("115", "t2t", "3")
    for (l2 <- lines) {
      if (l2.contains(str)) {
        containList += l2
      }
    }
  }                                               //> isStringInFile: (str: String)Unit

  for (c <- containList) {
    println(c)                                    //> t2t
                                                  //| 3
  }
```

This is a imperative solution. But is there a functional implementation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like **@mohit**'s solution but your expected result differs from his one. So this code works as your example:

```
val lines2 = List("2", "3", "4")
val lines = List("115", "t2t", "3")

val result = for {l <- lines
     l2 <- lines2
     if l.contains(l2)
} yield l

result.foreach(println)
```

Output:

```
t2t
3
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do that

```
scala>   val lines2 = List("2", "3", "4")
lines2: List[String] = List(2, 3, 4)

scala> val lines = List("115", "t2t", "3")
lines: List[String] = List(115, t2t, 3)

scala> lines2.filter(lines.contains(_))
res1: List[String] = List(3)
```

Another approach

```
scala> lines.intersect(lines2)
res2: List[String] = List(3)
```

Comment: The first approach seems rather unnecessary in light of the second.

Comment: If the lists are big you should consider converting them to Map (.toMap) before the intersect. Current solution runtime complexity is O(n^2); If you convert to map first it will be O(n)

Comment: @ChrisMartin True. Just wanted to show some simple methods if the OP is trying to learn.

Comment: @Maxim I agree. However converting a list to map will be a convoluted solution, unless am I missing something?

Comment: @mohit , well it depends on many details around that we don't have here. That's why I stated that this should be a consideration. One of the factors of this considerations is the size of the lists.